# Outlook saved msg gets updated after sending

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

Sometimes what I will do is create a template email and save it someplace on my computer and then go back to it to re-use the email. The issue that I am having is that if I open up that saved `.msg` file and then send it, the next time that I go into that `.msg` file the minor changes that I made to the email before sending will be there, but I never saved the email. Why is that happening, and can I fix it?

Even stranger, is that there is an old template that I have saved, and I can open up and send that email out freely without the `.msg` file being changed after sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save Outlook email message as .OFT. Then it will stay the same: Outlook will create new messages based on this saved template.

Comment: What's the difference between an `.OFT` and an `.MSG`?

Comment: Just file extension =) And because of the extension, Outlook works with it differently.